# The complement of the closure is open

Tags: general-topology

Is the complement of the closure is necessarly open in an arbitrary topological space (except the trivial case)?

In $\mathbb{R}$ with usual topology it is true.
But after some observations using the list of topologies from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_topological_space it looks like this is not the case in general space (I note it during wtiting the question). (Is it correct?) EDIT: IT WAS NOT CORRECT!

So the question is: what property does quarantee it for $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What are the counter-examples that you allude to?

Comment: If the closure is a closed set then its complement is open...

Comment: @CarstenS I dont understand what do you mean. If I take a in the topology {∅, {a}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}} then the compliment of its closure are not in this topology.  What property does have $\mathbb{R}$ which is connected to my question?

Comment: @DavidKraemer It is very interesting. I have learned that by operation of closure we get closed set.

Comment: In that example the closure of $\{a\}$ is the whole space, and its complement is $\varnothing$, which is in the topology.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Yes. I was wrong. So the compliment of the closure is open in any space?

Comment: The closure of any subset is closed (by definition) and its complement is an open set (also by definition).

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Thanks! It is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the closure of $ Y \subset X$ is the smallest closed subset of $X$ which contains $Y$, so its complement is, by the definition of closed set (set whose complement is open), open.